# Ask sample variance equation?

Tags: statistics

$$(n-1) S_x^2 = \Sigma_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X})^2$$

Is this equation always true? Or this relationship only holds for some specific distributions, like normal distribution?

Comment: Mh, isn't $S_x^2$ *defined* as $\dfrac1{n-1}\displaystyle\sum(X_i-\bar X)^2$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you show is most commonly used for the sample variance. For normal data it provides a good
estimate of the unknown population variance $\sigma^2.$

For a sample from a normal population with unknown mean $\mu$ and unknown (finite) variance $\sigma^2,$ your definition of $S_z^2$ leads to the relationship $\frac{(n-1)S_x^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(\nu = n-1).$ This relationship can be used to test hypotheses about $\sigma^2$ or to make a confidence interval for $\sigma^2.$

But there are exceptions for particular circumstances.

If the population mean $\mu$ is ***known*** and the population variance
$\sigma^2$ is unknown, then for normal data, the best estimate of
$\sigma^2$ is $\widehat{\sigma^2} = \frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i - \mu)^2.$ Then one uses the
relationship $\frac{n\,\widehat{\sigma^2}}{\sigma^2}
\sim \mathsf{Chisq}(\nu = n)$ for testing and making
confidence intervals.

And there are still other ways to estimate population variances from non-normal samples. For example, if you have a random sample $X_1, X_2, \dots X_n$ from
$\mathsf{Pois}(\lambda),$ then $\sigma_x^2 = \lambda$ and
the best estimate of the population variance is $\bar X =\frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i.$

Answer (score 0):

Relationship is general as long as variance is finite.

Derivation $(n-1)E(S_x^2)=\sum(E(X_i^2)-2E(X_i\bar{X})+E(\bar{X}^2)$.

$E(X_i^2)=\sigma^2+m^2$, sum is $n(\sigma^2+m^2)$

$\sum E(X_i\bar{X})=nE(\bar{X}^2)$.

$E(\bar{X}^2)=\frac{1}{n^2}(n(\sigma^2+m^2)+n(n-1)m^2)$, sum is $\sigma^2+nm^2$

Combine terms and $(n-1)E(S_x^2)=(n-1)\sigma^2$